# How to deploy docker image to another Ubuntu system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker. i am a python developer recently i got a task to packaging my django project and deploy it on another ubuntu.
so i planned to save django project as docker image and load it into another ubuntu system.
i saved the docker image
`sudo docker save -o /home/charles/Desktop/dockerdemo4_web.tar dockerdemo4_web`

by this command and loaded it with 
`sudo docker load -i dockerdemo4_web.tar`
after that i seen the docker image listed by `sudo docker images` but there is no container listed.
i dont know what to do now. let me know how to run my docker image(django project) to execute my django application as i did on source machine(sudo docker-compose up)

Comment: by executing `sudo docker run -it dockerdemo4_web bash` which leads to a seperate console like : `root@4dswf434:/code#` what is it?

Answer (score 1):

May be this help you:

`docker run --name app-container -p 8080:80 -it yours-image:latest /bin/bash`

and check running containers

`docker ps -a`

Comment: yes when i execute the command it leads to `root@4dswf434:/code#` if i put `ls` command it will list the dockerfile and yaml and requirements.txt.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation will help to understand, for example here is [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/.):  And [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount) is an example of working with the docker-compose.

Comment: Previously you wrote: by executing sudo docker run -it dockerdemo4_web bash which leads to a seperate console like : root@4dswf434:/code# what is it? 
*root@4dswf434* - yours new container. 

 This is your new container, which you received from the transferred image. And you are a in this container. Try running manually the daemons of jango, python - i.e. all those processes that are needed to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Docker image is just a template that is used to create runtime environment (container).
So if you can see docker image on the target environment then with correct docker run command you can create+start the container.

```
#>docker run --name friendly-name docker-image-name
```

**docker-compose up** will work if target environment machine has this utility installed and 
it looks for docker-compose.yml(default) file to help you in running the container.

Comment: what is that friendly-name?

Comment: you can use any name like my-app

Answer (score 0):

Also I advise you to look at the section of the file docker-compose.yml

for example:
*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
   web:
     build:.
     ports:
      - "3001: 80"
   db:
     image: mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

   adminer:
     image: admin
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 8080: 8080`
```

Here is interesting section "web". There is a build on the Dockerfile in the current directory. You can also add your images, including the one that was obtained with the help of "save / load"